# conflict with servo and dc motors

Tags: arduino

I was building an obstacle avoiding robot and was testing my motor shield (Adafruit Motor Shield V2 for Arduino).
I uploaded the code for the dc motors onto the arduino uno, a basic code for the simple motion but my servo also seems to be running.

How can I make it stop and check only the dc motors?

Connections are:

- servo pins to ser1 on motorshield.
- ultrasonicsensors' gnd and vcc to gnd and 5v of arduino respectively
- trig and echo to A4 and A5 respectively
- dc motors to M1 and M2 on motor shield
- and finally motorshield onto arduino.

This is the motor code I updated:

```
#include<AFMotor.h>
AF_DCMotor rmotor(1, MOTOR12_1KHZ);
AF_DCMotor lmotor(2, MOTOR12_1KHZ);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  rmotor.setSpeed(255);
  lmotor.setSpeed(255);
}
void loop() {
  rmotor.run(FORWARD);
  lmotor.run(FORWARD);
  delay(5000);
  rmotor.run(FORWARD);
  lmotor.run(BACKWARD); delay(1000);
  rmotor.run(FORWARD);
  lmotor.run(FORWARD);
  delay(5000);
  rmotor.run(BACKWARD);
  lmotor.run(FORWARD);
  delay(500); // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Generally. If you don't care about testing the servo you can unplug it (then it will be off). If you want to keep it plugged in, but you don't want it to move, then you actually need to set it at an angle, so that the [Arduino can keep it fixed in one place](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/4081).

So you probably just want to be fixing your servo to 90 degrees (mid-point), perhaps something like:

```
#include<AFMotor.h>
#include <Servo.h>

AF_DCMotor rmotor(1, MOTOR12_1KHZ);
AF_DCMotor lmotor(2, MOTOR12_1KHZ);
Servo servo;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  rmotor.setSpeed(255);
  lmotor.setSpeed(255);

  servo.attach(9);
  server.write(90);  // set servo to mid-point
}
void loop() {
  rmotor.run(FORWARD);
  lmotor.run(FORWARD);
  delay(5000);
  rmotor.run(FORWARD);
  lmotor.run(BACKWARD); delay(1000);
  rmotor.run(FORWARD);
  lmotor.run(FORWARD);
  delay(5000);
  rmotor.run(BACKWARD);
  lmotor.run(FORWARD);
  delay(500); // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

Comment: u mean fixing it at 0 degree or something like tat??

Comment: #include<AFMotor.h>
AF_DCMotor rmotor(1,MOTOR12_1KHZ);
AF_DCMotor lmotor(2,MOTOR12_1KHZ);
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  rmotor.setSpeed(255);
  lmotor.setSpeed(255);
 }

void loop() {
  rmotor.run(FORWARD);
  lmotor.run(FORWARD);
  delay(5000);
  rmotor.run(FORWARD);
  lmotor.run(BACKWARD);
  delay(1000);
  rmotor.run(FORWARD);
  lmotor.run(FORWARD);
  delay(5000);
  rmotor.run(BACKWARD);
  lmotor.run(FORWARD);
  delay(500);
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}  well this is my code for arduino. and also thank u for responding.

Comment: Yes, exactly, since you are leaving your servo plugged in, you probably want to fix it to some degree. The midpoint (90) could be a good choice. I wouldn't recommend trying to fix it to 0 or 180 the extremes could vary (if the servo isn't calibrated).

Comment: You are using the Adafruit Motor Shield V2 for Arduino?